# Invariant Violation when using Link component in a dynamic menu

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-redux

I'm building a Menu component which renders a list of links which are created using the react-router Link component.

This is the code which renders each item of the menu:

```
  <li
  style={{opacity: this.props.isDragging ? 0 : 1}}
  className="list">
            <Link to={ this.props.list.url }
                  activeClassName="active"
                  className={ this.props.owner && 'draggable'}>
                <span>{ this.props.list.title }</span>
                { this.props.owner ?
                    <div className="list-controls">
                    <span className="glyphicon
                         glyphicon-pencil"
                        aria-hidden="true"
                    onClick={this.setEditMode.bind(this, true)}>
                    </span>
                    <span className="glyphicon
                         glyphicon-remove"
                    aria-hidden="true"
                    onClick={this.deleteList.bind(this)}></span>
                </div> : null
                }
            </Link>
        </li>;
```

The menu is dynamic. This means that navigating to another url may re-render the menu with a different list of links. The problem is that when the menu is re-rendered, I get the following exception:

```
Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: findComponentRoot(..., .0.0.0.4.$12.0): Unable to find element. This probably means the DOM was unexpectedly mutated (e.g., by the browser), usually due to forgetting a '<tbody>' when using tables, nesting tags like '<form>, <p>, or <a>', or using non-SVG elements in an <svg>' parent. Try inspecting the child nodes of the element with React ID ``.
```

I've checked that the .0.0.0.4.$12.0 element is the `<a>` tag generated by the Link component in the first render.
I've also checked that if I don't use the Link component (and, for example, use a simple `<a>` tag instead), the exception goes away. Any thoughts?

UPDATE: Apparently the error showed up when I started using react-router-redux (formerly redux-simple-router).

Answer (score 4):

I ran into the same issue on a project using `redux-simple-router` (now `react-router-redux`) and was able to fix it by changing which lifecycle methods I was using to dispatch actions (which I was using to rerender a component with different `<Link>` components).

I created a reduced example in [a gist](https://gist.github.com/lukekarrys/a71aecac0426e86643b4) which I got working with [this revision](https://gist.github.com/lukekarrys/a71aecac0426e86643b4/revisions#diff-2652850356c0aeb1af0d634dc428bdd0R9).

In the gist there is a `<Page>` component which dispatches a `SYNC` action immediately and then a `DONE` action after 100ms which changes `render()` to show a loading indicator. Once loaded, the component was rendering some conditional elements, and one of them was a `<Link>` which was causing the same Invariant Violation.

Originally I was dispatching the actions from within the page's `componentWillReceiveProps` lifecycle method. When I changed it to `componentDidUpdate` the error went away. Here's the relevant code that I changed:

```
- componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
-   if (nextProps.params.param !== this.props.params.param) {
-      nextProps.dispatch(fetch())
-   }
- }

+ componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
+   if (prevProps.params.param !== this.props.params.param) {
+     this.props.dispatch(fetch())
+   }
+ }
```

On a side note, I noticed that the error wasn't exclusive to rerendering `<Link>` components. I was able to recreate the same error when using any element (like a `<span>` or `<a>`) with an `onClick` handler).